# Dart & flutter : How can I pass an implementation of an abstract class to the constructor of another class?

Tags: flutter, dart, interface, abstract

I have this class:

```
class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> implements OnLogin { 
    
   LoginVM _loginVM = LoginVM(this) // "this" doesn't work like Java for example.
   
   @override
   void onInvalidAccessToken() {
      _loginVM.loginWithRefreshToken();
   }

   @override
   void onInvalidRefreshToken() {
      _redirectToLogin();
   }
}
```

And this is the other:

```
abstract class OnLogin {
   void onInvalidAccessToken();
   void onInvalidRefreshToken();
   ...etc
}
```

Finally this is the class that should have the instance of OnLogin to call the callbacks.

```
class LoginVM {

  MyApi _api;
  AuthRepository _authRepository;
  OnLogin _onLogin;


  LoginVM(OnLogin _onLogin) {
    _api = MyApi.create();
    _authRepository = AuthRepository(_api);
    this._onLogin = _onLogin;
  }


  void loginWithToken() async {
    var token = await _secureStorage.read(key: Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
    if (token != null)
      _authRepository.getUser(token, _userStream);
    else
      _onLogin.onInvalidAccessToken();
  }

  void loginWithRefreshToken() async {
    var refreshToken = await _secureStorage.read(key: Constants.AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY);
    if (refreshToken != null)
      _authRepository.loginWithRefreshToken(refreshToken, _userStream);
    else
      _onLogin.onInvalidRefreshToken();
  }


  More code...

}
```

I would like to pass the OnLogin "interface" that implements the class with the keyword "this" like others languages, but it doesn't work in Dart.

Does anyone knows the way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you want to pass the class, when you can just `import` the file which consists of `OnLogin` and use it's functions there?

Comment: What do you mean? I want to call the functions from LoginVM...Like callbacks. Then I'll handle some things inside the callbacks in LoginScreenState.

Comment: Then show your full code, where is your LoginVM code here

Comment: I'm sorry, it's posted now.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much @scrimau